# How to store a function in a variable in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, function, variables

Let's say I want to store the function `y(x) = x + 2` in a variable.

Is there any way to save `y = x + 2`, and access as `y(x)`? For example, `y(2)`?

Comment: For functions with generic names like `y` the anonymous functions seem to be the way to go. However, for most you may want to just create regular functions. Note that you can have many functions in 1 file for easy handling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) is what you're looking for:

```
>> y = @(x) x+2;
>> y(2)

ans =

     4
```

Comment: +1 Technically, the [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) is the right-hand side `@(x) x+2`, and `y` is a [function handle](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html) to that anonymous function

Comment: @LuisMendo For general knowlage - for define this function, should I `syms x` first?

Comment: @user1798362 No, the `x` in the anonymous function's definition is an ordinary variable, not a symbolic variable